# How to set sourse map for d.ts files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ide, webstorm, rollup

I've created a TypeScript library. It has an `src` directory with `.ts` files and `dist/esm` directory, where all `.ts` file are converted into `.js`, `.js.map` and `.d.ts` files. The library is working, it has typings but there are some problems with the development process.

In the IDE (I use *Webstorm*) when I click to the component from my library I'd like to open a source file from `src` directory. But instead I open a typings declaration file (`.d.ts`).

I've found out that when I add to the `.d.ts` file a link to a source map like so:

```js
/// <reference types="react" />
import './styles/Button.scss';
export declare const Button: () => JSX.Element;
// The line below has been added
//# sourceMappingURL=Button.js.map
```

the IDE starts automatically open needed file from `src` directory.

And I'd like to know is it a correct way to open files from source directory of a library?

If it is, how can I automatically add these lines in every `.d.ts` files using *Rollup*?

If it's not, could you please describe how to do it in the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly I found out that there's a special field in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    declarationMap: true
  }
}
```

And now it works.